# Open jQueryUI Dialog when it doesn't have an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I open the below dialog when clicking some element?  Do I need to assign it to some variable (and thus do `myDialogVariable.dialog("open")` ) or add an ID to it (and thus do `$('#myDialogID').dialog("open")` )?

```
$('body')
.append('<div title="My Dialog"><p>Some HTML</p></div>')
.dialog({
    autoOpen    : false,
    modal       : true,
    open        : function() {},
    buttons     : []    
});

$('#someElement').click(function(){
    //Open above dialog
});
```

Comment: It's better to use `ID` or `class`. In your case you can call it like `$('div').dialog()` but only if this `div` is the only the one `div` in your page

Comment: @Pavlo.  No such luck with it being the only `div` in the page!  My objective was to ensure that the ID would never conflict with some other ID on the page.

Comment: `Id` **must** always be **unique** and you must pay attention on this to avoid any duplications of `Id`'s

Comment: @Pavlo  Yes, I know.  Concern was someone uses my plugin but does the rest of the JS themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have no way of selecting the element the way you defined it.

There are a few ways to do this.

One is (as you presumed) to add the defined element to a global variable, but is not the best way.

The simplest way to achieve your goal is to give it an ID. An id MUST be unique. If is not, you have a problem.

Another would be to add some kind of custom attribute, and select element with that attribute defined. But that would not respect the standards so would also suggest against it.

Edit: "@Pavlo Yes, I know. Concern was someone uses my plugin but does the rest of the JS themselves." -> You create something, you set some rules, comment them, make a documentation. Is the other guy's job (the one that is using your plugin) to develop according to your rules, if he wants to use your plugin. Still... being a plugin suggest to use the first method (the one with the var).

Comment: Instead of a global variable, I could add a namespace for all my variables in my plugin.

Comment: Of course, there are 999 ways to do this. That was from the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example for your according to your code: 
**HTML**

```
<input id="btnOpenDialog" type="button" value="Open Dialog" />
```

So, you were added some `div` element into `body` (One correction from my site is - added `Id` to the `div` element):

```
$('body').append('<div id="myDlg" title="My Dialog"><p>Some HTML</p></div>')
```

Then your `click` event will be the following:

```
$('#btnOpenDialog').click(function(){
  $('#myDlg').dialog();
});
```

Again, you should always pay attention on your `Id`'s that must always be **unique**
 
***Is that what you were asking for?***

Comment: @Is that what you were asking for?  Per the title, "Open jQueryUI Dialog when it doesn't have an ID".

Comment: @user1032531 If you don't have a rights to edit this `div` you could call your dialog like `$("div[title=\"Open Dialog\"]")` but I believe that this `div` is your element and you can do with it whatever you want - as an approach you can set an id like `myPersonalDialogId-bla-bla-bla` and I don't think that somebody will have the same id in his application